# Streaming the desktop through java?

Tags: java, video, stream, streaming, video-streaming

Using socket connections, how can I stream the screen view from one computer to the other withou third-party libraries?

Comment: If you want something like [VNC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_Network_Computing), you'll need to implement the [*remote framebuffer*](http://www.realvnc.com/docs/rfbproto.pdf) (RFB) protocol yourself. Any reason not to use any third-party library?

Comment: @miku I like to implement stuff myself, learn a lot that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A very simple solution would be to use `Robot.createScreenCapture()` to get a `BufferedImage`, then `ImageIO` to stream it.

Comment: But is this the best solution? Thats one image at a time to create video. How good is that? Are there better approaches? Like streaming the display port or similar? How does for instance Slack track an application, despite moving it around?